# Question regarding sed's multiple commands

Tags: sed

is `sed -e 'script' -e 'script'` the same as `sed "script;script"` ?

Moreover do those multiple commands operate during one scan of the file? Or is it the case that the more scripts you put the more scans/passes of the file it will do? (one per script)

Since sed is a scripting language, I am leaning towards the multiple pass theory... For example if you have `sed "script;script"` this is like having a sed script like this:

```
script
script
```

So it would be natural to assume that everything happends procedurally.

But how about `-e 'script' -e 'script'`?

And most importantly, is there a way to tell sed to only perform one pass, therefore saving valuable CPU cycles on large files? **And if sed cannot do that, is there another way in doing something like this ? (Maybe awk is more suitable for example? ect)**

Thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: Did you test your theory?

Comment: @muru how would you test it

Comment: By sending a huge file to `sed` over a pipe and observing `sed`'s memory and storage usage. Pipes aren't seekable, so, if `sed` wanted to do multiple passes, it would have to store all that data.

Answer (score 3):

- For each line of input, each expression/script is applied to it in turn. The command

  ```
  sed -e 's/apple/orange/g' -e 's/orange/red/g'
  ```

  would replace all occurrences of the string `apple` *and* `orange` with the string `red`.
- There is only *one pass* through the input data. `sed` handles streams, it is a *stream editor* after all, and the input stream doesn't even have to be seekable.

The example that you had,

```
sed -e "script1" -e "script2"
```

is the same as

```
sed "script1;script2"
```

which is the same as

```
sed -f file1 -f file2
```

where `file1` contains `script1` and `file2` contains `script2`, which is the same as

```
sed -f file
```

where `file` contains

```
script1
script2
```

or

```
script1;script2
```

Whether `sed` is suitable for your task is totally depending on the task. Just like `sed`, `awk` does not need to parse a file or input stream more than once. Some tasks are more suitable for `awk`, especially those that require aggregation of data.

`sed` is an editor, `awk` is more of a text processing language in comparison.